# Writing C# in a SharePoint-Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I'm working on a SharePoint-Hosted application and wondering how I can add C# code to the .aspx files.  When creating Auto-Hosted and Provider-Hosted apps, they displayed a C# script for every page.

Is this not possible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I personally don't like client side object model. Javascript and html feels like I am back to 90s can microsoft able to sovle this ?(using C# and still be able to deploy to cloud)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is the major limitation of SharePoint hosted apps.

To be able to run server side code you need to develop auto hosted or provider hosted apps.

[See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179887.aspx) for complete comparison between the hosting options

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I initially tried auto-hosted and provider-hosted apps, but wasn't able to use Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls to use the SPWeb and SPUser class functions. Can you use WebControls on provider/auto hosted apps?

Comment: In the App model, you are no longer able to use the server-side object model.  You are now using the client side object model.  You will want to use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client